# Cannot put Parcelable into bundle

Tags: java, android, parcelable

My question is fairly simple. I want to pass a List of objects from an Activity to a Fragment thanks to a bundle and Parcelable.

Basically, I make a simple retrofit call from the MainActivity, get a List of objects as an answer, then pass it to the fragment.

I've implemented parcelable to my object classes, but it's not working.

```
public class Result implements Parcelable {

// Variables
@SerializedName("geometry")
@Expose
private Geometry geometry;
@SerializedName("icon")
@Expose
private String icon;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("opening_hours")
@Expose
private OpeningHours openingHours;
@SerializedName("photos")
@Expose
private List<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<Photo>();
@SerializedName("place_id")
@Expose
private String placeId;
@SerializedName("rating")
@Expose
private Double rating;
@SerializedName("reference")
@Expose
private String reference;
@SerializedName("scope")
@Expose
private String scope;
@SerializedName("types")
@Expose
private List<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();
@SerializedName("vicinity")
@Expose
private String vicinity;
@SerializedName("price_level")
@Expose
private Integer priceLevel;

// Constructor
public Result(Geometry geometry, String icon, String id, String name, OpeningHours openingHours, List<Photo> photos, String placeId, Double rating, String reference, String scope, List<String> types, String vicinity, Integer priceLevel) {
    this.geometry = geometry;
    this.icon = icon;
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.openingHours = openingHours;
    this.photos = photos;
    this.placeId = placeId;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.reference = reference;
    this.scope = scope;
    this.types = types;
    this.vicinity = vicinity;
    this.priceLevel = priceLevel;
}

// Getters & Setters
/**
 *
 * @return
 * The geometry
 */
public Geometry getGeometry() {
    return geometry;
}

/**
 *
 * @param geometry
 * The geometry
 */
public void setGeometry(Geometry geometry) {
    this.geometry = geometry;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The icon
 */
public String getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

/**
 *
 * @param icon
 * The icon
 */
public void setIcon(String icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The id
 */
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 *
 * @param id
 * The id
 */
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 *
 * @param name
 * The name
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The openingHours
 */
public OpeningHours getOpeningHours() {
    return openingHours;
}

/**
 *
 * @param openingHours
 * The opening_hours
 */
public void setOpeningHours(OpeningHours openingHours) {
    this.openingHours = openingHours;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The photos
 */
public List<Photo> getPhotos() {
    return photos;
}

/**
 *
 * @param photos
 * The photos
 */
public void setPhotos(List<Photo> photos) {
    this.photos = photos;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The placeId
 */
public String getPlaceId() {
    return placeId;
}

/**
 *
 * @param placeId
 * The place_id
 */
public void setPlaceId(String placeId) {
    this.placeId = placeId;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The rating
 */
public Double getRating() {
    return rating;
}

/**
 *
 * @param rating
 * The rating
 */
public void setRating(Double rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The reference
 */
public String getReference() {
    return reference;
}

/**
 *
 * @param reference
 * The reference
 */
public void setReference(String reference) {
    this.reference = reference;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The scope
 */
public String getScope() {
    return scope;
}

/**
 *
 * @param scope
 * The scope
 */
public void setScope(String scope) {
    this.scope = scope;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The types
 */
public List<String> getTypes() {
    return types;
}

/**
 *
 * @param types
 * The types
 */
public void setTypes(List<String> types) {
    this.types = types;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The vicinity
 */
public String getVicinity() {
    return vicinity;
}

/**
 *
 * @param vicinity
 * The vicinity
 */
public void setVicinity(String vicinity) {
    this.vicinity = vicinity;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The priceLevel
 */
public Integer getPriceLevel() {
    return priceLevel;
}

/**
 *
 * @param priceLevel
 * The price_level
 */

public void setPriceLevel(Integer priceLevel) {
    this.priceLevel = priceLevel;
}

// Parcelable

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeParcelable(this.geometry, flags);
    dest.writeString(this.icon);
    dest.writeString(this.id);
    dest.writeString(this.name);
    dest.writeParcelable(this.openingHours, flags);
    dest.writeTypedList(this.photos);
    dest.writeString(this.placeId);
    dest.writeValue(this.rating);
    dest.writeString(this.reference);
    dest.writeString(this.scope);
    dest.writeStringList(this.types);
    dest.writeString(this.vicinity);
    dest.writeValue(this.priceLevel);
}

protected Result(Parcel in) {
    this.geometry = in.readParcelable(Geometry.class.getClassLoader());
    this.icon = in.readString();
    this.id = in.readString();
    this.name = in.readString();
    this.openingHours = in.readParcelable(OpeningHours.class.getClassLoader());
    this.photos = in.createTypedArrayList(Photo.CREATOR);
    this.placeId = in.readString();
    this.rating = (Double) in.readValue(Double.class.getClassLoader());
    this.reference = in.readString();
    this.scope = in.readString();
    this.types = in.createStringArrayList();
    this.vicinity = in.readString();
    this.priceLevel = (Integer) in.readValue(Integer.class.getClassLoader());
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Result> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Result>() {
    @Override
    public Result createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Result(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Result[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Result[size];
    }
};
}
```

And the MainActivity method call (simplified)

```
public void initRetrofitandCall(double latitude, double longitude, int PROXIMITY_RADIUS) {
GoogleApiInterface service = GoogleMapsClient.getClient().create(GoogleApiInterface.class);
Call<Example> call = service.getNearbyRestaurants("restaurant", latitude + "," + longitude, PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
            // Response List (working as intended)
            List<Result> listTest = response.body().getResults();
            Log.w("Nearby Restaurants", new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(listTest));  

            // Create bundle and put listTest in it (not working)
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable("valuesArray", listTest);

            try {

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
        }

    });

}
```

bundle.putParcelable("valuesArray", listTest); says **"wrong 2nd argument type required android.os.Parcelable**

All my model classes implements Parcelable, I'm only showing the Result.class to not make the post too long. I also tried with the Serializable way, and I get the same kind of issues. As if Parcelable or Serializable are not implemented in my model classes.

Thank you a lot for any help than you can provide me with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
```

convert your Arraylist to json using Gson and pass the json string as an argument to the fragment.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("valuesArray", new Gson().toJson(listTest));
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and then retrive the list of result in fragment like this,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
List<Result> result = new Gson().fromJson(getArguments().getString("valuesArray"), 
new TypeToken<List<Result>>(){}.getType());   
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **ParcelableArrayList** to put the list into the bundle

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("valuesArray", listTest);
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourFragment.class);
                    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Utils.LIST_TEST, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) listTest);
```